# how to make this query run fast

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
    SELECT id,type,source_id,link,short_link,cat_id,title,description,images,views,comments,published,publishedon FROM listings WHERE 
(YEARWEEK( FROM_UNIXTIME( publishedon ) , 1 ) = YEARWEEK( CURDATE( ) , 1 )) AND 
(id != 88587) AND 
(cat_id = '64') 
AND (deleted = 0)
AND (published = 1)
ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

**table explain** 
[image]
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `hash` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `source_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `short_link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` mediumint(5) NOT NULL,
  `title` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext,
  `content` mediumtext,
  `images` mediumtext,
  `videos` mediumtext,
  `views` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comments` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `comments_update` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `editor_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `auther_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdby_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `createdon` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `editedby_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `editedon` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `deletedon` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `deletedby_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `deletedfor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `publishedon` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `publishedby_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8956 ;
```

I cannot make any changes in fields types.

Is there any way to make it fast? 
It takes to execute 0.7518 sec,0.8776 sec.

Comment: Table definition would help together with the EXPLAIN

Comment: Query EXPLAIN please (that shows the expected execution plan). Better to add the `CREATE TABLE` statement instead of that image.

Comment: Also, what would you consider fast?  Half a second?  0.1s?  Less?

Comment: added, i have 5 or 6 queries like this in one page , its very hard, i want it smaller as possible

Comment: The first image shows "key: MUL" on the `hash` column, but the `create table` does not show the index, are you sure these are right?

Comment: And we (and YOU) definitely need results of [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) used on the query you want to optimize. Thats a special function which shows HOW the query is executed and some estimates of rows "visited".

Comment: ops,one picture from localhost and the other from the real server, i think this will not affect the base problem

Answer (score 0):

This should help significantly (unless everything is cat 64):

```
INDEX(cat_id, deleted, published)
```

If 'they' won't add that index (or let you add it), warm up your resume.